# `SELECT a.*, array_agg(b)` requires `GROUP BY` for all columns in `a`

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Question:** 
How can I specify I want an array of `child` related to the `parent` by `uniq_hash` (and all the other columns) without actually specifying every single column in the `GROUP BY`?

The database is **PostgreSQL**.

---

I have these tables: `parents` and `children`

**`parents`**

```
| id | col1 | col2 | ... | col250 | uniq_hash |
|----|------|------|-----|--------|-----------|
| 1  |      |      |     |        | <hash>    |
```

**`children`**

```
| id | bcol1 | bcol2 | ... | bcol50 | uniq_hash |
|----|-------|-------|-----|--------|-----------|
| 1  |       |       |     |        | <hash>    |
```

```
       +---------+
   +---+  Parent +---+
   |   +----+----+   |
   |        |        |
+--v--+  +--v--+  +--v--+
|Child|  |Child|  |Child|
+-----+  +-----+  +-----+
```

---

I'm trying to add an array of `child` to a `SELECT * parent FROM parents WHERE ...;` query.

The resulting query would look something like:

`SELECT parents.*, array_agg(children) as children FROM parents LEFT JOIN children ON parents.uniq_hash = children.uniq_hash WHERE ...;`

---

The issue is that `parents` is ~250 columns wide, and to do that it appears that I need to list every single column in `parents` as a `GROUP BY`. This is... suboptimal.

---

I **have** tried this, and it executes - but it just returns the two columns (ie: it's missing headers on the `parent` data column):

`SELECT parents, array_agg(children) as children FROM parents LEFT JOIN children ON parents.uniq_hash = children.uniq_hash WHERE ... GROUP BY parents;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you don't.  You can just use:

```
GROUP BY parents.id
```

And if `id` is declared to be `unique` or `primary key`, then Postgres will accept the syntax.

If the `id` is not declared in this way, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (SELECT array_agg(c.children)
        FROM children c
        WHERE p.uniq_hash = c.uniq_hash
       ) as children
FROM parents p;
```

Comment: It appears as if this table I was handed has `id` -- but may not define it as unique or as a key. I'll check that out and report back.

Comment: Thanks. Your edit worked exactly as written. I'm still on minute 23 of checking if each value of `id` is unique in this billion-row table.

Comment: If the query worked there must be a primary key or unique constraint/index defined. If that definition is on id you do not need to check for unique values; that is ***guaranteed***.